# Can't Get PHPMyAdmin to recognize configuration file after update(Keep getting blowfish_secret too short error)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just updated PhpMyAdmin via the command line (i added the PPA manually). I keep getting an error that says "The secret passphrase in configuration (blowfish_secret) is too short. I have created my own config.inc.php file in /etc/phpmyadmin using the command

```
sudo cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php
```

In this file (my config.inc.php) I have set

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'wE(G|]=VPxy}UddLC8[sC1J8y$yElEU]7#_#*1fDas;doifje';
```

And restarted the server with

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I also restarted the mysql server with

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

I am still getting the error telling me that the blowfish_secret key is too short. (Yes, I have tried setting the key to EXACTLY 32 characters as well. This did not work either) I have refreshed the page, cleared the cache. I even tried setting all permissions to 7

```
sudo chmod -R 777 phpmyadmin
```

(JUST TO SEE if it would work. Don't kill me for being desperate XD) Still, no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As it turns out, I had to edit

```
/var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php
```

Just put exactly 32 random characters between the single quotes, like so

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'GGlkGmgpsp]9_[b2lXr5*a$BV4XO1lm+guJU3k(p$9z^9';
```

NOTE: I didn't think I would need to spell this one out, but your random string CAN NOT contain a single quote....

Comment: Be aware that it has to be *exactly* 32 chars/bytes long, at least from v5.2.0

Comment: I used more than 32 characters, and I kept getting the same error. Then I used exactly 32 characters as per @Grindlay's suggestion. And it worked.

Comment: I have added @Grindlay's feedback to the original answer. Must be *exactly* 32 characters

Answer (score 8):

Please do check /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

Comment: The config.inc.php that I reference in the OP is in /etc/phpMyAdmin. My solution is posted above...